# Sum different rows in a data frame based on multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following data frame:

```
dataset = {
     'String': ["ABCDEF","HIJABC","ABCHIJ","DEFABC"],
    'Bool':[True,True,False,False],
    'Number':[10,20,40,50]}

df = pd.DataFrame(dataset)



      String   Bool  Number
0  ABCDEF   True      10
1  HIJABC   True      20
2  ABCHIJ  False      40
3  DEFABC  False      50
```

I would like to sum the rows of the column `Number` where `Bool` is `False` to the rows where `Bool` is `True`:

The rows can be matched and summed together if the reverse of String of one row is not equal to the String of the row.

- In this case `ABCHIJ` where `bool` is `False` is not equal to the reverse of `ABCDEF` so I sum the numbers: 10+40.
- `HIJABC` where `Bool` is `True` is summed to `DEFABC` where `Bool` is `False` the outcome is `70`

Expected output:

```
    String   Bool  Number
0  ABCDEF   True      50
1  HIJABC   True      70
2  ABCHIJ  False      40
3  DEFABC  False      50
```

I hope my explanation was good enough, is there a way to achieve the above outcome ?

Comment: Your explanation is unclear, what is the summation condition? Also, what have you tried to do it?

Comment: How does this scale when say you have another row `4 XYZ False 70`?

Comment: @FoundABetterName, there would not be a 4th row... I expect for it to be a group of 4 rows everytime.

Comment: Will there be 2 Trues and 2 Falses always?

Comment: but `DEFABC` is not reversed string of `ABCDEF` !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is like this:

```
df_true = df[df['Bool'] == True]
df_false = df[df['Bool'] == False]

for i in df_false['String']:
   idx = df_true[df_true['String'] != (i[3:] + i[:3]) ].index[0]
   current_num = df.loc[df.index == idx, 'Number'].values[0]
   added_num = df[df['String'] == i]['Number'].values[0]
   df.loc[df.index == idx, 'Number'] =  current_num + added_num
```

I hope it helps

Comment: thank you man, I really appreciate your help.  It worked, this is what I've been looking for. :)